# Definir a cor de uma série em um novo gráfico na planilha

Tags: excel-vba

No VBAProject tenho uma linha que seleciona uma determinada série do gráfico

```
Sub MudaCor()
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Select
End Sub
```

Sendo "n" o numero da serie que eu preciso selecionar.

as cores das series de um gráfico, seja de barras ou mesmo linhas, o excel determina por si.

Como mudar a cor dessa série, usando uma linha de codigo no VBA, para a cor que eu desejar??

```
Sub MudaCor()
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Select
    ExemploSerie.Mudacor (???)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um script para gerar um novo grafico, conforme os parametros de cor definidos e celulas de uma coluna, conforme linhas que contenham valor em celula.

> A Função ***Contalinhas*** serve para detectar onde há celulas com valores, para
>   delimitar os dados do grafico:

```
 Function ContaLinhas(area As Range) As Long

    Dim celula As Range, TotalLinhas As Long
    TotalLinhas = 0
    For Each celula In area
        If celula <> "" Then
            TotalLinhas = TotalLinhas + 1
        End If
    Next
    ContaLinhas = TotalLinhas
End Function
```

> Aqui eu tenho o ***Range*** e as ***Cores*** do grafico definidas

```
Sub NovoGrafico()       


'Os dados estão contidos na coluna "A" (apenas como exemplo)

C = ContaLinhas(Range("A:A"))

'Cria um novo grafico com os parametros a serem definidos

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Superar").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(C, 2))
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(C, 1))
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Border.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Ou seja,

Tenho um script que cria um novo gráfico com as cores Branca e Preta, respectivamente, Interior e bordas.